# QT application for drawing basic graph

Tags: qt, boost-graph, graph-visualization

I am trying to write visualization program to be able to draw such netlists:
 [image]

Could you please show an examples  how can I do this?

After some googling I found out this examples:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview-elasticnodes.html

http://algoholic.eu/qnodeseditor-qt-nodesports-based-data-processing-flow-editor/

I found out that boost has a library named boost graph library(BGL), which can be used for such use cases. Could you please show  how can I draw above netlist using this library?

Answer (score 3):

You can try using QCustomPlot, it is very lightweight - http://www.qcustomplot.com/

It can be used to plot graphs, bars, waves, charts etc. In your case you would only need

[QCPItemRect](http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPItemRect.html) and lines ofcourse

Comment: As far as I know this module has only futures to create charts. Is it?

Answer (score 3):

I would look into [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org) and the various open source Qt code that integrates it.

From a quick search on "Qt Graphviz"

- [qgv](https://github.com/nbergont/qgv)
- [loqt](https://github.com/CapelliC/loqt)

Answer (score 2):

Boost does not support visualization in the BGL. It does have functions to read and write graphViz and other formats (Bullet 23 in table of contents: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/table_of_contents.html).

As the other posters mention GraphViz may be an option. If you don't want to do any operations on the graph then BGL is likely not useful.